# Sharing data in between multiple angular applications

Tags: angular, web, deployment, web-deployment

I am having multiple Angular projects. (not multiple apps in one angular project). For an example Client Management,Search Criteria, Result page, Shopping Cart, Booking Management  etc..  Each items are separate Angular projects & deploying as separate a war files.

My requirement is what is the better way to pass the data in between multiple apps. We can send data through the URL as query params and also we can store them on browser's local storage.  Is there any security risk of storing data on local storage or what is best solution for this?

Comment: Store them in a database on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I suggest is to implement a service, store and retrieve data locally
else store and retrieve data from cookies refer [ng-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies) 
else you can have properties defined in your app component and pass them as input params to child components which will be a hard task to manage your code.
All depends on your data, But I suggest, if you do want to preserve data for next time you visit the app use the cookies, else go ahead with local storage in a service.